# ASP.NET WebAPI StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

The scenario I am talking is local debugging scenario as I have not deployed to azure yet.

I have a MVC Web App authenticating against AAD that calls WebAPI
I have the right permission set in the AAD tenant, the reason I say it set correctly because I am able to get the AccessToken for the WebAPI, but then when I try to call the WebAPI it gives me the following error

```
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?xxxxxxxxxx
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Sun, 27 Mar 2016 02:06:31 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 61
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}
```

Code

```
string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
NaiveSessionCache nsc = new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID);

AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority, nsc);                
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);

result = authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(todoListClientId, credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
Uri webApiUri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}{1}", todoListBaseAddress, "/api/TodoList"));

string accessTknString = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result.AccessToken));
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, webApiUri);
request.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), string.Format("Bearer {0}", accessTknString));
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: No one else experienced this? I am encountering this in a localhost environment during debug.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573145/asp-net-mvc-4-401-access-denied