# C# PostAsync - {StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized' with ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I am using ASP.NET MVC4 and calling a method within a controller from one MVC4 project to another, using PostAsync.  I am not using any authentication attribute within the called controller or method.

Referencing this link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573145/asp-net-mvc-4-401-access-deniedhttp://)
Fixed my issue when running application locally and calling PostAsync to application on server. Now, when I deploy the application to the server and try to call the other application I get the unauthorized error. What am I doing wrong?

Both application running in IIS are using the same site, and the same application pool.

Using remote debugging, this is the server response:

```
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: private
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
  WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
  WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Date: Fri, 23 Jun 2017 13:44:19 GMT
  Content-Length: 6644
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}}
```

And this is my code:

```
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.EnvironmentRootPath)})
        {
            List<string> orderNumbers = NumList;
            var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("orderNumbers", string.Join(",", orderNumbers))
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

            // call sync
            var response = client.PostAsync("CentralBroadcast/broadcastNewOrder", content).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //
            }
            else
            {
                //
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does your application have authentication/authorization implemented? If not then most probably its webproxy authentication issue. You may try setting property UseProxy=false on HttpClientHandler.

Comment: Yes, it's using windows authentication. Authorization checks are done in key areas but not on this controller yet.

Comment: the, "UseDefaultCredentials = true" got everything working while calling application on server from local server running within visual studio, but now that both applications are on server it is having the issue.

Comment: @PankajKapare where is a good place to start to try to understand why it is failing only on the sever?

Comment: Check if there is some independent functionality in both applications which doesn't depend on each other and has authentication and authorization implemented. See if those parts of both applications are working as expected. That will eliminate possibility of windows authentication not working as expected.

Comment: @PankajKapare I am passing the windows credentials in the request.. which works locally as it is using my credentials since I am running everything locally. Now, when the application makes a call from the server will it still use my credentials? I am using Network for the application pool authentication.

Comment: Does network service have access on second application when you make call from first application? First application will use app pool's credentials while calling second application when deployed on server. Its working locally because its using your credentials to call second application.

Comment: @PankajKapare    Oh okay, I thought using, "{ UseDefaultCredentials = true })" would pass the windows logon credentials to be used. So it does not then? And if network service doesn't have access to the application how and where can that be adjusted. Thank you.

Comment: Or better yet, since the PostAsync call is initiated by a user completing an action, can I tap into the HttpContext user and attach the logon information to the HttpClient object used for the PostAsync?

Comment: Even tried temporary impersonation (which was verified working) using this link: 
https://books.google.com/books?id=BTiwKwx2GeEC&pg=PA161&lpg=PA161&dq=pass+current+handler+to+new+httpClient&source=bl&ots=P-AzZlxPN6&sig=e1zRDcL73QtfpaDYkuMRIeOTpSM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwqKbx1tvUAhVFPD4KHaoyCtcQ6AEIWTAJ#v=onepage&q=pass%20current%20handler%20to%20new%20httpClient&f=false://    No luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be due to accessing a local web application from the same server that hosts IIS 5.1 or greater and uses a fully qualified domain name.

The domain names of the FQDN need to be white listed in the registry, and I was able to do this by completing the steps below:

**It is always a good idea to create a backup of registry before making any adjustments**

1)  Click **Start**, click **Run**, type regedit, and then click **OK**.

2)  In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key: 
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0**

3)  Right-click **MSV1_0**, point to **New**, and then click **Multi-String Value**.

4)  Type BackConnectionHostNames, and then press ENTER.

5)  Right-click **BackConnectionHostNames**, and then click Modify.

6)  In the **Value data** box, type the host name or the host names for the sites that are on the local computer, and then click **OK**.

7)  Quit Registry Editor, and then restart the IISAdmin service.

For more detailed information reference:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/896861/you-receive-error-401.1-when-you-browse-a-web-site-that-uses-integrate